# Whats Wrong in it?

Tags: c++

Problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/migratory-birds/problem

Test Case Link: https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/33294/input04.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1573162301&Signature=MgpSHa3lxX%2FwYwumjzAmF8uviZE%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain

for this test case i cant get any output why ?

Thanks in advance

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long long n,i=0,num=0,mx=0,r=0;
    cin>>n;
     long long arr[6]{0};
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>num;
        arr[num]++;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]>mx)
        {
            mx=arr[i];
            r=i;
        }
    }
    cout<<r;
}
```

Comment: Please note that the question should include all necessary information and a clear question. “What’s wrong” is not clear and the question doesn’t explain what the code should do or how it fails to do so. Links to outside resources may break and will make the question useless for others.

Comment: Access to the test case is denied. Ideally, you should avoid giving links and provide a specific problem instead of giving away a general problem. Also, tell what did you try and did it change anything. In absence of this, you are unlikely to get a good response. Did you try printing a newline at the end?

Answer (score 2):

This looks problematic:

```
 long long arr[6]{0};
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>num;
    arr[num]++;
}
```

If the input value read into `num` is greater than 5 (or less than zero), undefined behavior will exist when a value is written into an invalid memory location offset from `arr`.

Comment: Please check the problem link.. And input is always <0 && 6>

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that your program isn't robust from invalid input.

Comment: @SohanuzzamanSoad Links rot, are often blocked by firewalls, and can take the clicker of to a wonderful page that enslaves their computer and harvests their credit card number. Don't use them as sources of important information and don't be surprised when no one reads them

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with you code i got accepted all test cases. But the solution can be return in more optimized way
[image]